# fragment setVisibility NullPointer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have problem with working on fragments.

I am in Activity 1. I add fragment to this activity and call method.
Then this method calls other metod but in fragment class.
In this method i want to button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) but it throws me NullPointer.

Code:

Own class container:

```
public class Container
{
    private ImageButton ib;
    private int stan;
    private int wartosc;

    public Container(ImageButton ib, int stan, int wartosc)
    {
        this.ib = ib;
        this.stan = stan;
        this.wartosc = wartosc;
    }

    public int getStan()
    {
        return stan;
    }

    public int getWartosc()
    {
        return wartosc;
    }

    public void setWartosc(int wartosc)
    {
        this.wartosc = wartosc;
    }

    public void setStan(int stan)
    {
        this.stan = stan;
    }

    public ImageButton getButton()
    {
        return ib;
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
ImageButton b1;
Container button1;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.face_fragment, container, false);


    b1 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nr1);

    // i also tried something like that:
    b1 = (ImageButton) V.findViewById(R.id.nr1);


    context = V.getContext();

    addResources();

    button1 = new Container(b1, 1, 0);

    return V;
}
```

And fragment of method which throw nullpointer:

```
public void setVisible()
{       
    if(all)
    {
        button1.getButton().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //here nullpointer
```

Please, help me, i have no idea....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".FaceFragment"
android:weightSum="20"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:weightSum="30"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/nr1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="button1Click"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/domyslnie" />

     <ImageButton
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/nr2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="button2Click"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/domyslnie" />

      <ImageButton
          android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/nr3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="button3Click"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/domyslnie" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:weightSum="30"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/nr4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="button4Click"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/domyslnie" />

     <ImageButton
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/nr5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="button5Click"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/domyslnie" />

      <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/nr6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="button6Click"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/domyslnie" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LOGCAT:

```
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute     method of the activity
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3660)
1-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17152)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3655)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    ... 11 more
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at pl.brysp.game.speedsquare.FaceFragment.setVisible(FaceFragment.java:189)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at pl.brysp.game.speedsquare.FaceFragment.setRemember(FaceFragment.java:142)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    at pl.brysp.game.speedsquare.Game.start(Game.java:63)
11-06 18:58:20.289: E/AndroidRuntime(24368):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Can you post your entire container class and fragment class?

Answer (score 2):

`getActivity().findViewById` will not work on `onCreateView` because the view is not attached yet.

Use `V.findViewById` instead

[image]

Comment: look two lines of code after getActivity().findViewById

Comment: @PawełBryś Have you tried changing that routine to `onActivityCreated`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira yes i tried it in two ways in onActivityCreated

Comment: Show us your logcat so we can know what and when `setVisible` is being called.

Comment: @PawełBryś Remove the onClick's of your xml and set them on your fragment manually instead. Start by one and see if that solves. If so then change all the others to the fragment aswell